# In file upload server, the windows size from server to client is so small? when setting the option tcp_nodelay

Tags: tcp, network-programming, netty, serve

Here is my question. I have a file upload server using netty. The client upload a 100k file part and then the server responses 200.

When I set tcp_nodelay false on server, the window size is small, and never gets bigger, as the pictures follow
client ip = 30.4.112.7; server ip = 100.69.212.129

[image]
When I set tcp_nodelay true on server, the window size gets bigger and bigger. why?
[image]

Comment: What operating systems are on your client and server computers?

Comment: client is on mac os, server is on redhat os.When i use ios as  client, the situation is the same. confusing=.=

Comment: Is the packet capture made on the server or the client?

Comment: on the client..